# How to create account balance for each users in asterisk freePBX system?

Tags: voip, asterisk, pbx

I have an asterisk server up and running.

Users connect via extensions(IAX2).

How do i create balance account for these users?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @JakeGould, what the hell is wrong with you? go disturb someone... idiots...

Comment: @avidPostill, you too...

Comment: @karel, yes you idiots...

Comment: @Scott don't you guys have anything better to do?

Comment: @fixer1234 read the question if you don't understand go and learn something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asterisk is PBX, not billing system.

You can create custom dialplan using DB function and cdrs, but that required non-trivial skills

Simplest method is use billing system like http://a2billing.org.

Comment: Thanks @arheops, I have no voip providers, because i am a voip provider, so how exactly i need to configure for my queries?  like: do i have create 1000 extensions for my customers? or how should i link these freepbx and a2billing?

Comment: You should setup a2billing as outbound trunk using Local/ channel as Local/$DIALNUM$a2billing/n . Also you should put in every extension accountcode field value of username from a2billing. Note, you HAVE setup a2billing correctly(not just install) acordinly to INSTALL file in a2billing tarball and setup ratecards.

Comment: any tutorial or guidance DYI something like that?

Comment: Sure. Alot of tutorial about a2billing configuration, including video. Unfortanly it  is not even two hour job, so can't be described in SO format.

Comment: pardon me? just point me out where i can find these (and please don't say google)

Comment: https://sysadminman.net/blog/2009/getting-started-with-a2billing-part-1-setting-up-a-trunk-447